# How can I use shared memory in nodejs program?

Tags: node.js, shared-memory

I have some C++ services running on server and a node server program listening to a specific port. Can I use shared memory between C++ services and nodejs program?
I want users to send data through nodejs server and those C++ services access them.
Is it possible?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10965201/632951

Answer (score 5):

I tried write a C/C++ binding of shared memory access from nodejs.
https://github.com/supipd/node-shm

Still work in progress (but working for me), maybe usefull, if bug or suggestion, inform me.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a binding to C/C++.  Start from http://howtonode.org/how-to-module (Writing a Binding section).

Within the binding code, you can use shared memory to your C++ service, although it may make more sense to link directly to the service if it makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, I must read it and then think about my problem again.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using shared memory from Node.js.
Can't you have your node.js talk to your service over TCP or anything message-based ?

Comment: @Floby: When nodejs application and c++ service are in same os is it a good idea? (using TCP)

Comment: Yes it is. TCP is portable to any platform. If you design your application this way you do not have to worry about compatibility issues.

Comment: @Floby, TCP is slow. That's the reason for shared memory.

Comment: @Pacerier No, not really.

Comment: @Floby, compared to shared memory, yeah, really.

Comment: Shared memory needs to be used with extreme care. But for a large data set it is millions of times faster than TCP.